# Virtual inheritance: Why does it work when only one base class has "virtual" keyword? Is there a better way?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I want to implement a class hierarchy in C++:

- I need interfaces so I can provide multiple implementations.
- I need common methods in all the classes. But I need to be able to override specific methods.
- Constructors all take at least one parameter.

Simplified I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>

class IClass {
public:
    virtual int commonMethod() const = 0;
};

class Class : public virtual IClass {
protected:
    int commonValue;

public:
    Class(int commonValue) : commonValue(commonValue) {}

    virtual int commonMethod() const {
        return commonValue;
    }
};


class IClassDerived : public virtual IClass {
public:
    virtual void specialMethod() = 0;
};

class ClassDerived : public Class, public virtual IClassDerived {
public:
    ClassDerived(int commonValue) : Class(commonValue) {}

    virtual void specialMethod() {
        // do something
    }
};


class IClassDerived2 : public virtual IClassDerived {
public:
    virtual void specialMethod2() = 0;
};

class ClassDerived2 : public ClassDerived, public virtual IClassDerived2 {
public:
    ClassDerived2(int commonValue) : ClassDerived(commonValue) {}

    virtual void specialMethod2() {
        specialMethod();
    }
};


class IClassDerived3 : public virtual IClassDerived2 {
public:
    virtual int commonMethod() const override = 0;
};

class ClassDerived3 : public ClassDerived2, public virtual IClassDerived3 {
public:
    ClassDerived3(int commonValue) : ClassDerived2(commonValue) {}

    virtual int commonMethod() const override {
        return 4711;
    }
};


int main() {
    ClassDerived foo(1);
    ClassDerived2 foo2(2);
    ClassDerived3 foo3(3);

    std::cout << foo.commonMethod() << " " << foo2.commonMethod() << " " << foo3.commonMethod() << " " << std::endl;
    // 1 2 4711

    return 0;
}
```

I now have two questions:

- Why does this work at all?

  - If I try without virtual inheritance I get errors "‘specialMethod’ is ambiguous" and "...  because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘ClassDerived’: virtual int IClass::commonMethod() const". Because of the two base classes every member is there two times which results in these errors. Ok.
  - If I do virtual inheritance and specify both base classes with "public virtual" I get "no matching function for call to ‘Class::Class()’". Researching showed me that in case of virtual inheritance I need a default constructor for the base classes.
  - By trial-and-error I found the solution above. But I don't understand why it works so far. What happens when only one base class is "virtual" but not the other one?
- Is there a better way? I managed to get this little example to compile but in reality my classes are complexer and I am afraid this only works in this little snippet and I am not seeing future problems this could bring up...

Comment: The nice thing about interfaces is that you *don't* need virtual inheritance.  There is nothing to inherit.

Comment: @HansPassant Are you sure? The OP seems to inherit from "interfaces" via two base clauses; won't you end up with a separate (partion of the) vtable for each one? [Simplified example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e7bbe1c60ceb55f)

Answer (score 7):

I have recently found a workaround that does not need virtual inheritance (see below).

Basically, the language requires the use of *virtual* inheritance in this case to solve the problem directly since you inherit multiple times from the same class. Without virtual inheritance, you'll end up with this:

```
Interface0  Interface0  Interface0
    ^           ^           ^______
    |           |                  \
Interface1  Interface1              Impl0
    ^           ^__________________   ^
    |                              \  |
Interface2                          Impl1
    ^______________________________   ^
                                   \  |
                                    Impl2
```

There are multiple "instances" of the `InterfaceX` base class, which are independent. Consider the `Interface0` instance from the path `Impl1 -> Interface1 -> Interface0`. The `Impl0` class does not inherit from *that* instance of `Interface0`, hence it does not implement its virtual functions. Note that this is useful if all these interface classes were stateful classes (with data members) instead of pure interfaces.

But in this particular situation, where you only inherit from an *interface*, virtual inheritance isn't required *in theory*. We want to get to the following picture:

```
Interface0 _
    ^     |\
    |       \
Interface1 _ Impl0
    ^     |\   ^
    |       \  |
Interface2 _ Impl1
          |\   ^
            \  |
             Impl2
```

Theoretically, `Impl1` could define one single vtable with the entries from `Impl0` implementing the virtual functions from `Interface0`, and the functions from `Impl1` implementing the virtual functions from `Interface1`. The result would be a single vtable with no offset computations required (hence no need for virtual inheritance).

But, alas, the language doesn't define inheritance this way -- it doesn't make a difference between abstract classes and pure interfaces. It lets you only override virtual functions through sideway-inheritance (`Impl0` overriding virtual functions of `Impl1 -> Interface1 -> Interface0`) if you inherit them via virtual inheritance. By inheriting virtually, you specify that you indeed inherit only *once* from `Interface0`, so both paths from `Impl1` to `Interface0` (direct inheritance and via `Impl0`) yield *the same* class.

Virtual inheritance has several drawbacks, since it must allow cases where the location of the base class (relative to a subobject) can only be determined at run-time. **However**, there's a workaround that doesn't need virtual inheritance.

It is often more useful to write a class first self-contained, and then adapt it to an interface. The interface is typically defined by the surrounding architecture, and hence not necessarily general for that class. By separating the interface from the implementation, you allow reuse of the implementation with a different interface.

If we put this together: We cannot use multiple inheritance to implement virtual functions side-ways, and we want to separate interface from implementation. We end up with: Either, we don't let our implementation derive from anything (this leads to boilerplate code) or we derive linearly, the only inheritance from an interface at the top.

By writing our implementation classes as class templates, we can derive linearly and pass the top interface to be derived from up to the base implementation class:

```
struct Interface0 {
    virtual void fun0() = 0;
};

struct Interface1 : Interface0 {
    virtual void fun1() = 0;
};

struct Interface2 : Interface1 {
    virtual void fun2() = 0;
};


template<typename Interface = Interface0>
struct Impl0 : Interface {
    void fun0() {}
};

template<typename Interface = Interface1>
struct Impl1 : Impl0<Interface> {
    void fun1() {}
};

template<typename Interface = Interface2>
struct Impl2 : Impl1<Interface> {
    void fun2() {}
};


int main()
{
    auto x = Impl2<Interface2>(); // or simply: Impl2<>()
    Interface2* p = &x;
}
```

Note that we use inheritance for both: implementing `Impl1` in terms of `Impl0`, and passing the extended interface to our base class.

The case in `main`, `Impl2<>`:

```
Interface0
    ^
    |
Interface1
    ^
    |
Interface2 _
          |\
            \
             Impl0<Interface2>
               ^
               |
             Impl1<Interface2>
               ^
               |
             Impl2<Interface2>
```

Another case, `Impl1<>`:

```
Interface0
    ^
    |
Interface1 _
          |\
            \
             Impl0<Interface1>
               ^
               |
             Impl1<Interface1>
```

Comment: Another way to solve this is by defining separate interfaces, but I guess that's less convenient and efficient (multiple vtables). E.g. `struct Interface0 { virtual void fun0() = 0; }; struct Interface1 { virtual void fun1() = 0; }; struct Impl0 : Interface0 { void fun0(); }; struct Impl1 : Impl0, Interface1 { void fun1(); }`

Comment: "_alas, the language doesn't define inheritance this way_" Hopefully, the language doesn't say that non virtual inheritance behaves as virtual inheritance. You have both.

Comment: @curiousguy Sorry, but I don't understand your comment. Do you mean my workaround uses both virtual- and non-virtual inheritance?

Comment: No, I am pointing out that you can't complain that the semantics of exclusive (non virtual) and shared (virtual) inheritance are different. There is no such thing as a "pure interface". Non virtual inheritance always means non virtual inheritance. Why would you expect non virtual inheritance to sometimes behave as virtual inheritance?

Comment: @curiousguy If there was a concept of a *pure interface* in the language, then I'd like to have special semantics for inheriting from it -- or rather, in order to get these special semantics, one would have to introduce *pure interfaces* into the language. From a theoretical point of view, I agree there's just exclusive and shared inheritance, however the implementations of both are different, and the implementation details leak into the semantics of virtual inheritance (e.g. `static_cast` cannot downcast to a virtually derived class).

Comment: If you have a pure interface (I presume with only trivial constructors and no data members), I think you are suggesting that it wouldn't matter whether there is only one instance of that almost empty base class subobject in the complete object. Well, it wouldn't matter except for address comparison!

Comment: @curiousguy No, I'm not suggesting that it doesn't matter. As we can see in the OP, it does matter with the current specification of the language. What I'm trying to say is that there's a use-case for an additional kind of inheritance behaviour (in addition to non-virtual and virtual inheritance).

Comment: It looks like you got the inheritance for Interface1 and Interface2 swapped around in your solution code?

Comment: @JeremyW.Murphy Looks like it indeed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to initialize virtual base classes in all derived class constructors. Thus, if you had

```
class ClassDerived : public virtual Class, public virtual IClassDerived {
//                          ^^^^^^^
```

Then in the constructors of `ClassDerived2` and `ClassDerived3` you would have to initialize `Class` despite that it seems to be initialized in the constructor of `ClassDerived`:

```
ClassDerived2(int commonValue) : Class(commonValue), ClassDerived(commonValue)  {}
ClassDerived3(int commonValue) : Class(commonValue), ClassDerived2(commonValue) {}
```

The reason for this is `[class.base.init]/7`:

> A *mem-initializer* where the *mem-initializer-id* denotes a virtual base class is ignored during execution of a constructor of any class that is not the most derived class.

---

Regarding whether there is a better way, personally I'd rather use aggregation and no virtual inheritance, though it requires writing some boilerplate forwarding code:

```
class IClass {
public:
    virtual int commonMethod() const = 0;
};

class Class : public IClass {
protected:
    int commonValue;

public:
    Class(int commonValue) : commonValue(commonValue) {}

    virtual int commonMethod() const {
        return commonValue;
    }
};


class IClassDerived : public IClass {
public:
    virtual void specialMethod() = 0;
};

class ClassDerived : public IClassDerived { // no inheritance from Class
public:
    ClassDerived(int commonValue) : m_class(commonValue) {}

    virtual int commonMethod() const {
        return m_class.commonMethod();
    }

    virtual void specialMethod() {
        // do something
    }

private:
    Class m_class;
};

// and so on
```